# Python, SQLAlchemy, MySQL: Insert data between existing records

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Unfortunately I couldn't find any useful information on this topic. I have an existing database with existing tables and also existing data in it. Now I have to add new data in between the existing data. My code would look something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
INSERT INTO table_name(data) VALUES('xyz') 
WHERE DATETIME(datetime) > DATETIME('2017-01-01 02:00:00');
```

I have created an image for a better understanding of my question.
Please take notice, that I need the Primary Key to adapt to the made changes as you can see in the picture. My tools are Python, SQLAlchemy and MySQL. I look forward to every help.

[image]

Comment: what is the purpose of this? why would you want the primary key to adapt, when you could just get rows based on the date, if that's what is important.

Comment: @Cicero The table is active and gets new data every few minutes and I want it to be clean. Could you please give an example on `get rows based on the date`

Comment: alright, but i don't see any reason to change the primary key.   Example: `SELECT FROM table * WHERE datetime=your_datetime_variable`   
I'm not sure whether the SQL query is completely correct or whether you are using sqlalchemy's ORM, which would be
`session.query(YourObjectType).filter_by(datetime=your_datetime_variable).first()`

Comment: Thank you, I actually know how to select a table, but I need to know how to append new data into an existing table without putting it to the end, but instead in between other rows. I hope you understand my question.

Comment: The only half decent solution i can think of is to use the date as the id. But that would require you to only have unique datetimes, e.g no duplicates.

Comment: The datetime data is not unique but I think it could still work for me.

Comment: As @Cicero is saying, you will be doing many unnecessary writes by inserting values in the middle--you will need to perform an update on every single row after the new value. Assuming that your issue is you want the data to be ordered by timestamp, you would be much better off adding an index on the timestamp column and querying for the ordered data: `session.query(table_name.datetime, table_name.data).filter(func.and_(table_name.datetime<start, table_name.datetime<end)).order_by(table_name.datetime.asc())`